# Is it posible in flutter to create a button that opens the email app with the email account "TO" already writen?

Tags: flutter

I wante to create a buton to be used when the suer wants to report a problem they can press it an will send them to their email app with my email already writen on it so they only need to write the email and I was wondering if that is a posibility on flutter.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Take a look at the [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher#supported-url-schemes) package. You can even set the subject and the body of the email.

Answer (score 2):

Just search through the flutter packages. I personally have used [flutter_email_sender](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_email_sender) which has a pretty full feature set, including subject, body and also attachments.

e.g.

```dart
final Email email = Email(
  body: 'Email body',
  subject: 'Email subject',
  recipients: ['example@example.com'],
  attachmentPaths: ['/path/to/attachment.zip'],
);

await FlutterEmailSender.send(email);
```